# Vue3, v-bind at template or at style? any performance differences?

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vuejs3

Just a little question to Vue3 experts, in terms of developing a professional project:

```
<script setup>
const fontColor = 'orange';
</script>

<template>
  <h2 class="onlyHere">Hello!</h2>
</template>

<style>
.onlyHere { color: v-bind(fontColor) }
</style>
```

OR

```
<script setup>
const fontColor = 'color: orange';
</script>

<template>
  <h2 v-bind:style="fontColor">Hello!</h2>
</template>

<style>
</style>
```

Both work, but I don't know which is the best implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which elements you want apply a style.

In the first example you applied font color style to ALL **h2** elements. You can also add "scoped" attribute to a  block to prevent leaking styles to other components.

In the second - ONLY to the element that has inline style.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, i edited the original question to clarify my point

Comment: its not about the scopes, its just about v-bind on template or on Styles

Comment: Well, it changes nothing :) When you bind styles in a <style> block you apply this style to all elements that has a spicified tag, class, id (depends on a selector of a rule). But when you bind style inline to a specific element, you apply this style only for a specific element. Inline style will not apply to other elements, even if they have the same class. That's the difference

Comment: So if you deen to apply style to only one specific element bind a style in template then. If you need to apply a style to a class/tag/etc. - bind it in <style> block.

Comment: To keep the question clean, in the example link to the id. <h2 id="onlyHere">Hello!</h2>, #onlyHere { color: v-bind(fontColor) }